# horizontal scrolling on ipad using zurb foundation

Tags: css, ipad, grid, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I'm building a responsive site using the Zurb Foundation framework for the first time.

It's going smoothly so far, but when testing on an iPad in portrait orientation, I'm getting some horizontal scrollbars.

I checked my widths and I think they are ok, what am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the .row class may be it

try adding a maxWidth property to it